# railtiesがバージョン違いのせいか、LoadErrorが出てrailsコマンドが実行できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

以下リンク先にある内容を実行した後、今回の問題に遭遇しました。

[rails sした時にalready initialized constant FileUtils::VERSIONとwarningが出てくる - Qiita](https://qiita.com/zQmjRAb73seN5RM/items/ecb9e19ee8f3e9af6018)

`railties`を5.2.3にすれば解決できるのかと思い、`railties 6.0.0`の対象と思われるディレクトリ削除や対象のgemのアンインストールなどしてみましたが、結果は変わらず、上のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

**railsコマンド実行時に表示されたエラー**

```
$ rails s
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /Users/pc/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
/Users/pc/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/pc/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/exe/rails (LoadError)
```

**実行環境** (ローカル)

Rails 5.2.3 
Ruby 2.5.1

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0.a"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/ and Gem::Version.correct?($1) then
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

if Gem.respond_to?(:activate_bin_path)
load Gem.activate_bin_path('railties', 'rails', version) #23行目
else
gem "railties", version
load Gem.bin_path("railties", "rails", version)
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

# CSSフレームワークとして追加
gem 'materialize-sass', '~> 1.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: 初めての起動で失敗したのでしょうか、それとも動いてたものが動かなくなったのでしょうか？ `Gemfile`の中身を書いてもらえるともう少し何かわかるかもしれません。

Comment: それはそうと「対象と思われるディレクトリ削除」をされたそうですが、gemの追加や削除を手動で行うと状態がわからなくなるので基本はbundleやgemのコマンドラインからのみ追加・削除を行ってください。たぶん一旦 `~/.rbenv`以下を削除して`rbenv`を再構築したほうが安全だと思います。

Comment: コメント、アドバイスありがとうございます！`rbenv` の再構築をやってみたいと思います！m(__)m

Comment: おかげでなんとかなりました！本当にありがとうございます！

Comment: 解決したようでよかったです。もし具体的な解決策が残っていれば回答として投稿してもらえると同じような問題で困ってる人の助けになるかもしれないのでよろしくおねがいします。