# rails sでnokogiri (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

初心者です。
この前質問をした問題からrbenvの再インストールをしていると`rails s`はできるが`rails t`はできない状態になり、下に書いたよなエラーメッセージが出力され、nokogiriが見つからないと言われてしまいました。
調べてもクリティカルなものが見つからなかったので、何かヒントになるようなことなどあれば教えていただきたいですm(__)m

以前した質問: [railtiesがバージョン違いのせいか、LoadErrorが出てrailsコマンドが実行できない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/60234/loaderror%e3%81%8c%e5%87%ba%e3%81%a6rails%e3%82%b3%e3%83%9e%e3%83%b3%e3%83%89%e3%81%8c%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

```
$ rails test
/Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:33:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/loofah-2.3.1/lib/loofah.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rails-html-sanitizer-1.3.0/lib/rails-html-sanitizer.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:62:in `<module:Helpers>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:6:in `<module:ActionView>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionview-5.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/context.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sass-rails-5.1.0/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
smallShip:pop-tale ike$         from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sass-rails-5.1.0/lib/sass/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sass-rails-5.1.0/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/workspace/pop-tale/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from /Users/ike/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

・Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'


gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'materialize-sass', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

恐らく`bootsnap`のキャッシュの問題なので一旦キャッシュを削除してみてください。

Qiitaに同様の症状と思われるものの対策がありましたので引用します。

[bootsnapのせいでRails5.2とかが動かない人へ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/cyborg__ninja/items/d15b50500f4ffb069feb)

> bootsnapはCacheファイルを作るんでこれを消します。
>
> 自分のRailsプロジェクトディレクトリの tmp/cache へ行く
>   bootsnap-load-path-cache と bootsnap-compile-cache を消す(rmコマンドでok)
>   これで、動かなかったRailsアプリにアクセスしてみましょう。

Comment: 無事解決できました.ありがとうございますm(__)m